# Iphone: How do I add a text view that the font size decreases to fit text view size when needed to

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextview

I am trying to make a `UITextView`, where the font size is adjusted to fit the size of text view. For example if you type a lot of text, and it is about to fill up the text view, the text will get smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder you adjust the attributes of the text view. Make sure to select autoshrink, adjust minimum font size to .2 (or whatver you want) (scale).  Whenever you type it will be shrunk and fit in the text view.

All of these can be found under the attribute inspector.

Comment: I dont see where autoshrink is.

Comment: It's not available for an `UITextView`. It's available for `UILabel`.

Comment: I also just thought of something. Why do you need it to shrink? The text view will scroll through all of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

define the max size you want the font to be. I typically put this in my .h file

## define kDefaultFontSize 24.0

Then in your .m file where you add the text to the UITextView you would place something like:

```
myTextView.text = @"Some long string that will be in the UITextView";
  myTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize];
```

//setup text resizing check here

```
if (myTextView.contentSize.height > myTextView.frame.size.height)
 {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (myTextView.contentSize.height > myTextView.frame.size.height)
 {
        myTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize-fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}
```